# How can i make this work code work in php with those quote's?

Tags: php, input

My code is this and i don't know how to figure this out: I need the value to be $aantalRijen[0]["QuizNaam"];!

```
$output = array();
$output['quizNaam'] = $aantalRijen[0]["QuizNaam"];

$html .= '<input readonly type="text" tabindex="-1" class="randomQuiz" value="<?php echo $output['quizNaam']; ?>">';

echo $html;

?>
```

Please help me if you need to know something just ask me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `<?php` tags when you're *already in PHP*.  You just want to concatenate the values like any other string:

```
$html .= '<input readonly type="text" tabindex="-1" class="randomQuiz" value="' . $output['quizNaam'] . '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing between single and double quotes.

You can use them interchangably.

Following is the solution:

```
<?php
$output = array();
$output['quizNaam'] = $aantalRijen[0]["QuizNaam"];
$html .= '<input readonly type="text" tabindex="-1" class="randomQuiz" value="' . $output['quizNaam'] . '">';
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html .= '<input readonly type="text" tabindex="-1" class="randomQuiz" value="' . $output['quizNaam'] . '">';
echo $html;
```

[See result](https://eval.in/487512)